# Login with LDAP using JSF 2,1 & Apache Tomcat

Tags: java, mysql, authentication, ldap

More than a problem, I need to perform authentication using jsf. I have developed a login, which receives a username and password that are stored in MySQL. Upon login from the Active Directory, this should take the username and password of AD, which, I suppose, should be the same as that of MySQL.

Then, to enter the system, you no longer see the login, but directly the main or home page.

I hope your help and thanks in advance.

Greetings.

Comment: I'm afraid you need to be a *lot* more precise what you've got working and what isn't. I have worked with MySQL, AD and LDAP, and your question makes absolutely no sense to me.

Comment: @BalusC: As you can see in the accepted answer, the problem mainly lies in the Java code, not the JSF code. Without the java-tag the Java syntax isn't properly highlighted.

Comment: @BalusC: So in your opinion the question was answered by providing JSF code? As previously mentioned, the problem was in the Java part. So it was primary a Java question. The fronted could have been implemented by JSF, JSP etc. The GUI technology is irrelevant here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This my solution, it worked for me:
Edit faces-config.xml:

```
<lifecycle>
        <phase-listener>
            com.xxx.admin.security.Login
        </phase-listener>
    </lifecycle>
```

class Login:

```
    public class Login implements PhaseListener {
    private static final String USER_LOGIN_OUTCOME = "login";
     @Override
        public void afterPhase(PhaseEvent event) {
            FacesContext context = event.getFacesContext();
            if (userExists(context)) {
                // 1. Update last login
                // 2. may be expired ???
                ExternalContext extContext = context.getExternalContext();
                try {
                    ETT_UserDTL tmpUser = (ETT_UserDTL) extContext.getSessionMap().get(User.USER_SESSION_KEY);
                    if (!Authenticator.authenticateUser(tmpUser, context)) {
                        // send the user to the login view
                        reLogin(context);
                    } else {
                        ;
                    }
                    // allow processing of the requested view
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    SystemLogger.getLogger().error(ex);
                    ClientMessage.logErr(ex.toString());
                    reLogin(context);
                }
            } else {
                // send the user to the login view
                reLogin(context);
            }
        }
    private boolean userExists(FacesContext context) {
    // Need re-check authenticator here.
    // Check user exist
    ExternalContext extContext = context.getExternalContext();
    return (extContext.getSessionMap().containsKey(User.USER_SESSION_KEY));
}
private void reLogin(FacesContext context) {
        // send the user to the login view
        if (requestingSecureView(context)) {
            context.responseComplete();
            context.getApplication().
                    getNavigationHandler().handleNavigation(context,
                    null,
                    USER_LOGIN_OUTCOME);
        } else {
            ;
        }
    }
    }
```

LDAPAuthentication:

```
public class LDAPAuthentication {

    static String ATTRIBUTE_FOR_USER = "sAMAccountName";

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Attributes authenticateUser(String username, String password, String strDomain, String strHost, String dn) throws NamingException {

        String searchFilter = "(&(objectClass=user)(" + ATTRIBUTE_FOR_USER + "=" + username + "))";
        // Create the search controls

        SearchControls searchCtls = new SearchControls();
        // searchCtls.setReturningAttributes(returnedAtts);
        // Specify the search scope
        searchCtls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.OBJECT_SCOPE);
        String searchBase = dn;
        Hashtable environment = new Hashtable();
        environment.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        // Using starndard Port, check your instalation
        environment.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://" + strHost);
        environment.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");

        environment.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, username + "@" + strDomain);
        environment.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);

        LdapContext ctxGC = null;
        try {
            ctxGC = new InitialLdapContext(environment, null);
            // Search for objects in the GC using the filter
            NamingEnumeration answer = ctxGC.search(searchBase, searchFilter, searchCtls);
            while (answer.hasMoreElements()) {
                SearchResult sr = (SearchResult) answer.next();
                Attributes attrs = sr.getAttributes();
                if (attrs != null) {
                    return attrs;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            SystemLogger.getLogger().error(e);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Authentication:

```
public static boolean authenticateLDAPUser(String strUser, String strPass, String strDomain, String strHost) throws NamingException, Exception {
        LDAPAuthentication ldap = new LDAPAuthentication();
        Attributes att = ldap.authenticateUser(strUser, strPass, strDomain, strHost, "");
        if (att != null) {
            try {
                ETT_UserDTL tmpUser = (ETT_UserDTL) DataUtil.performAction(DATA_UserGUI.class, "getInfByUserName", strUser);
                tmpUser.setPassword(strPass);
                if (!otherAuthenticate(tmpUser)) {
                    Authenticator.removeUser();
                    return false;
                } else {
                    ;
                }
                pushUser(tmpUser);
                return true;
            } catch (TelsoftException ex) {
                SystemLogger.getLogger().error(ex);
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            updateLoginFail();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but still I have a doubt. When I verify that AD credentials equal to those stored in the database? and I have a method login () that is in my JSF backing bean. That omit it and use the method "authenticateLDAPUser" you mentioned earlier? Greetings and thanks.

Comment: That omit com.xxx.admin.security.Login ?

Comment: That what I have already added line, which checks whether a user is authenticated or not. My question is if the AD user and password must be the same as the username and password of the database, and the user has permissions, but these are in the database.

Comment: That's same to me, permissions and roles are stored in database, AD is only use to anthenticate user !

Comment: Then, the user of user AD operates independently of the database, ie are different users? thanks again

Comment: Do you understand my solution :)