# Block logged in users from viewing page but allow anonymous users

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee

Using Java-EE 6, JSF2, Glassfish 3.1.

What is the best method to redirect a user away from certain pages, such as the 'log in' page when they're already logged in?

I was going to user the following in each of the pages I did not want logged in users to access:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{aBean.checkIfLoggedInAndRedirect()}" />
</f:metadata>
```

Is there a more elegant method?

Something like a security constraint for anonymous users so that no other roles (i.e. logged in users) can view these pages.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15648328/login-with-ldap-using-jsf-2-1-apache-tomcat/15652173#15652173

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to handle authentication/authorization with users in a database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9965708/how-to-handle-authentication-authorization-with-users-in-a-database)

Comment: @BalusC I'm trying to stop logged in users from going to certain pages including: /login.xhtml, /register.xhtml, /loginError.xhtml. When they attempt to rel-ogin on these pages they get an exception: `The servlet exception thrown said: Attempt to re-login while the user identity already exists`
@RongNK I don't think this actually stops a logged in user from viewing certain pages.

Answer (score -1):

With no other better suggestions, I have used the following on each page I don't want to a logged in user to see. Not the most solid implementation (as the page is still there).

```
        <c:if test="#{request.remoteUser != null}">
            <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=/home" /> 
        </c:if>
```